# Standard Conventions

Tags: java, standards

Is it true that Standard convention is that variables and method identifiers start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that is the Java standard naming convention, and it's also a naming convention put into use by many other standards used by companies/coders out there. Names that begin with capitals are typically used for types, as in class names.

Also, check out the Java naming conventions documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.
>
> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use. One-character variable names should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables. Common names for temporary variables are i, j, k, m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for characters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Find out by yourself at the [source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 0):

The is the accepted Java convention.

Other conventions:

`PackageName.ClassName.MethodName`, aka Microsoft style (See: .NET, Win32 API)

`namespace::class::some_static_method_name()`, aka C++/STL/C style (also seen in most C code bases as `libraryname_function_name()`)

`schizo_PhrenicStylewhenyoucantKeep_things_working` - not recommended.